# Javascript - Execução várias vezes

Tags: javascript, loop, modal

Galera, boa tarde

Tenho um código JS + CSS para abrir uma imagem no tamanho normal através de uma imagem reduzida. Consegui fazer isso com uma única imagem, no entanto, quando coloco num looping em php, ocorre um erro.

Segue abaixo:

```
<-- Aqui deveria começar o loop em php -->

<img id="myImg" src="imagem_grande.jpg">

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
<span class="close"><img src="imagem_close.png"></span>
<img src="imagem_grande.png" class="modal-content" width="100%">  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>

<-- Aqui deveria fechar o loop em php -->

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var img = document.getElementById('myImg');

var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function(){
modal.style.display = "block";
modalImg.src = this.src;
modalImg.alt = this.alt;
captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```

Não tenho prática nenhuma em JS.

Agradeço a ajuda!

Abs!

Answer (score 0):

Os erro prováveis são:

- 1 . Definir o mesmo atributo de `id` para cada imagem e modal.
- 2 . Modificar somente uma imagem e uma modal.
- 3 . Você não está percorrendo todas imagens e modals criadas.

Para fazer seu código funcionar será necessário modificar o HTML. Crie um container e coloque a imagem e a modal dentro dele. Adicione uma classe para a imagem da execução variada, e também para alguns elementos da modal. Para simplificar:

```
<div class="row">
    <img class="my-img" src="imagem_grande.jpg"/>
    <div class="modal">
        <span class="close-btn">
            <img src="imagem_close.png"/>
        </span>
        <img src="imagem_grande.png" class="modal-content" width="100%">
        <div class="caption"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

. Agora, teste isso com JavaScript:

```
var rows = document.getElementsByClassName("row");

/** ... Iterate each row with image and modal **/
for(var i = 0, row; row = rows[i]; i ++) {
    /* The big image */
    var myImg = row.getElementsByClassName("my-img")[0];
    /* Modal elements */
    var modal = row.getElementsByClassName("modal")[0];
    var modalCaptionText = modal.getElementsByClassName('caption')[0],
        modalCloseBtn = modal.getElementsByClassName('close-btn')[0],
        modalImg = modal.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];

    myImg.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = 'block';
        modal.src = this.src;
        modalImg.alt = this.alt;
        modalCaptionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
    };

    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    modalCloseBtn.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    };
}
```

Comment: Não rodou, meu caro. Postei o JS igual vc mencionou acima, sem modificações. Posto novamente o código php, agora com mais detalhes, incluindo o loop while:

Comment: while($arquivo = readdir($diretorio)) 
{
$analisa = explode(".",$arquivo);
if ($analisa[1] == "jpeg" or $analisa[1] == "jpg")
{    
if($verificador==0) echo "<tr>";
?>
<th align="left">
<div class="row">
<img class="my-img" src="<?php echo $path.$arquivo; ?>"/>
<div class="modal"><span class="close-btn">
<img src="imagens/facebook_yellow.png"/>
</span>
<img src="<?php echo "fotos/".$categoria."/".$arquivo; ?>" class="modal-content"><div class="caption"></div>
</div>
</div>
</th>  
<?php
if($verificador==3) { echo "</tr>"; $verificador=-1 ;} $verificador++;
}
}

Comment: @Felipe Atualizei. Eu errei a string de uma classe css no js (de "close" para "close-btn": `var modalCloseBtn = modal.getElementsByClassName('close-btn')[0];`). Seu PHP está correto.

Comment: Se eu te falar que ainda não deu certo, vc acredita? =(

Comment: @Felipe Bem, viu o console? Não tem problema. Isso é bem fácil de corrigir! PS: pelo menos aqui funcionou.